# Delimit SQL Server output using custom string

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv

I am running a job in MS SQL Server that outputs a text file with white space in between columns.  What I'd like to do is specify a specific character sequence between each column as a delimiter.

For example, I'd like the output to look like:

```
Apple%%%red%%%fruit  
banana%%%yellow%%%fruit  
onion%%%White%%%veggie
```

In this example, %%% is the delimiter.

How can I do this?

Comment: Is this `MySQL` or `SQL Server`?  They are not the same thing...

Comment: Title says `MySQL` assume this is an error? How are you generating this file at the moment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are using the output file of the job step, and the output file is currently structured something like this:

```
---- --------
row1 somedata
row2 somedata
```

You could just concatenate the columns using '+' and fit the percent signs in as appropriate. So the job step definition would contain:

```
select column1 + '%%%' + column2 from table1;
```

And the output would look like:

```
---------------
row1%%%somedata
row2%%%somedata
```

This assumes that you are OK with concatenating each row of results into a single column. You will need to cast/convert non-character column values for this to work.

Comment: select column1 + '%%%' + column2 from table1;  doesn't work but
select column1 ,'%%%',  column2 from table1; does.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you are looking for the T-SQL equivalent of Oracle's P/SQL command "set colsep" command.  This command lets you alter the delimter of the output.  TO make it semicolon, for example, you would call:

> set colsep ";"

But in SQL Server... I see the way to do it.

Use the "bcp" utility and you can specify the delimiter and write to your file.  He are instructions:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx

Look at the -t option to change the separator.